# JSON, Obj C, Safety and null checks

Tags: ios, json

I am working on an app that retrieves dense multi layered business objects back from a webservice. I have in Obj C created classes that represent and map the Webservice object properly ( ie : user object, post object, group object )

Now I am getting data back as a json, and for some data points the response comes back with some parts of the data is null, or some portions of the object are just not there ( like a user object with no last name). Naturally I would start checking if the

```
 JSONRESPONSE
```

Has value for firstname, and then lastname, and then city, etc , etc.

Obviously there is a lot of redundancy in this, and I don;t want to write the same check over and over again, but thinking of a class method in a utilities class I have.

Anyone has ideas on this? whats the best approach to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you parsing this JSON?  How is `null` represented in the parsed document object model?

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with it is to have your classes use NSKeyValueCoding, and then setup some validation method that takes some data structure (e.g. array of attribute names) and check for required attributes, default values, etc. The rest is up to you, if you want to do some logging, set default values, etc. The data structure really depends on how much validation you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding categories which do the `null` & `nil` check for you. To avoid crash because of `nil` insertions you can return empty strings. For instance, below is a category on `NSDictionary` that helps retrieving non nil/null strings.

```
- (id)nullSafeObjectForKey:(NSString *) iKey {
    id retrievedValue = [self objectForKey:iKey];

    return ([retrievedValue isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || retrievedValue == nil) ? @"" : retrievedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for `NSString`,`NSArray`,`NSDictionary`,`NSData`,`UIImage`

```
- (BOOL)isObjectEmpty:(id)object {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || object == nil) {
            return YES;
        }
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            if (object == nil || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(length)] && [(NSString *)object length] == 0)) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            if (object == nil || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(count)] && [(NSArray *)object count] == 0)) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            if (object == nil || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(count)] && [(NSDictionary *)object count] == 0)) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
            if (object == nil || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(length)] && [(NSData *)object length] == 0)) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
        else if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
            if (object == nil) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }
```